# How to map the Duration type to Interval?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm creating a Slick Postresql table that contains a `Interval` field, that I want to represent as a `Duration`

```
case class Object(id: String, aproxDuration: Duration)
class Objects(tag: Tag) extends Table[Object](tag, "OBJECTS"){
  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def expectedDuration = column[Duration]("expected_duration")
  def * = (id, expectedDuration) <> (Object.tupled, Object.unapply)
}
```

To support this, I've installed the `slick-pg` extension and created a Profile that extends `ExPostgresProfile, PgDate2Support, PgRangeSupport` but I'm not sure why is it not finding the implicit `TypedType` for `Duration`

Comment: Have you also `object ExtendedAPI extends API with  DateTimeImplicits with RangeImplicits` and `override val api: ExtendedAPI.type = ExtendedAPI` in your profile?

Comment: yes sir, I do have it.

Comment: aditionally I was wondering if the Duration type is from java.time or scala.concurrent

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.time.Duration

import com.github.tminglei.slickpg.{ExPostgresProfile, PgDate2Support}
import slick.lifted.ProvenShape

trait MyPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile with PgDate2Support {

  override val api = MyAPI

  object MyAPI extends API with DateTimeImplicits
}

object MyPostgresProfile extends MyPostgresProfile

case class Object(id: String, aproxDuration: Duration)

object Tables {

  import MyPostgresProfile.api._

  class Objects(tag: Tag) extends Table[Object](tag, "OBJECTS") {
    def id: Rep[String]                 = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def expectedDuration: Rep[Duration] = column[Duration]("expected_duration")
    def * : ProvenShape[Object]         = (id, expectedDuration) <> (Object.tupled, Object.unapply)
  }

}
```